# Applying a filter on toolbox of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, toolbox

Is it possible to apply a filter to the toolbox of Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 ? I find it not so comfortable to find the widget I want.

Comment: you can create your tab for useful control/componnets

Comment: @AmritpalSingh: that's a good idea :) Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @AmritpalSingh : How to do that ?

Comment: Right click on toolbox add tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create your tab for useful control/componets.

Comment: Right click on toolbox add tab name as you find suitable